# how to localized scripts of new page requested by ajax?

Tags: javascript, wp-localize-script

I'm using ajax to load pages in WP ( all links of my theme works with ajax) and when i go from a page to another, I remove old script tag ( current page ) and add scripts of requested page dynamically(by javascript codes).
There is a big problem, my localized variable of new page, added to page normally but doesn't recognized by my script.(Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: portfolioObj is not defined)
is there anyway to do that?
I should mention that this problem occurs just for variables that are specific for requested page and we don't have them in current page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us your code.